# How to make dependency in makefile so that target is built when bazaar revision changes?

Tags: makefile, bazaar

I have a script that is designed to generate a config.h in the source tree, to be used by the code at compile-time. Information included in this includes the bazaar revision number.

My project is based only on a Makefile. I would like to add config.h as a target to be built when the script to make config.h is changed or the bazaar revision changes.

Is there a file in the .bzr directory that would change when the revision changes or something else I could use to get this type of dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steven said you might use last-revision file.

But as another approach you can consider to use post_change_branch_tip hook, and call build script for config.h automatically every time branch tip is changed.

http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/bzr.2.0.0/en/user-reference/index.html#post-change-branch-tip

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .bzr/branch/last-revision has what you want...

EDIT:  To properly handle the case of building past revisions, it honestly might just be easier to rebuild the config file every time you do a build, especially if it doesn't take too long...

Comment: This is true. But you may have problems with lightweight checkouts because the latter has no this file in working tree, but only in master branch.

Comment: It always stores the last revision, though. Not the current.

If I want to go back and do a build a few revisions ago, then it won't work right.

Comment: You can't go back without changing branch tip.